# password authenticated email sending in spring

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc, spring-security

How do i authenticate password for the email id.Currently it is sending mail without authentication,so how do i authenticate password   for mail.username given in propert file.
    **below code is there in spring-servlet :**

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="${mail.host}" />
<property name="port" value="${mail.port}" />
<property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
<property name="javaMailProperties">
<props>
<prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
<!-- <prop key="mail.smtp.debug">true</prop>  -->
</props>
</property>
  </bean>

**Mail Sending Part :**
SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
if(UserEmailId != null){
email.setFrom(userFrom);
email.setTo(UserEmailId);
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setText(MessageBody);
mailSender1.send(email);    
}

**mail property file :**
#Email address/account for sending emails from system.
mail.username=<from email id>

#Password for accessing email account
mail.password=<password>

#Mail server hostname or IP
mail.host=<host>

#Mail server port
mail.port=25

#Mail transport protocol
mail.transport.protocol=smtp

#Mail authentication enabled true/false
mail.smtp.auth=true

#smtp TLS enable true/false
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
```

Comment: the mail sender takes care of authentication. Try using a wrong password and check if the mail is getting sent.

Comment: I tried with wrong password but it works.

Comment: that is because your mail server doesnt support `smtp` authentication. or may not be configured for smtp authentication

Comment: your mail server host should be something like `smtp.*` and port no. 587.

Comment: @Nikhil : my mail server host is provided by the network team in my company and as per they say port should be 25 but i tried with other ports such as 587 but couldn't resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set following true and try again

```
<prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nopes still the same.

Comment: Make sure you are using valid port and hostnames.